# Keycloak: authenticate against other systems and put their tokens into JWT Access Token

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, jwt, keycloak

Problem:

- There are 3 systems each using its own kind of auth mechanisms and own type of tokens. User needs to pass creds to authenticate there.
- Our app uses OAuth2 and it needs to communicate with those systems, but it doesn't have user creds to do authentication on their behalf.

Idea:

- Keycloak is used as OAuth2 Server - user is redirected there and enters his creds
- Keycloak uses the creds to authenticate with the 3 systems and puts their tokens into JWT
- When the user is redirected back with the grant - our app uses the grant to get the JWT. All the tokens are there and it's possible to fetch them.

Is this a possible solution in Keycloak or other Auth tools? If yes - how? If not not - what are the alternatives?

PS: We've written a plugin for Keycloak that does this and it works. General impression: it's too hacky to have systems with different auth mechanisms.